# Restrict User to Delete Document Library Item in Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

In SharePoint Document Library , user can not delete the Folder because we don't provide delete option but user can still open document library in explorer and easily delete the folder 
Is there any way to Protect folder in explorer view ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can restrict User by adding event receiver on document library.
we can add code on item deleting event that properties.cancel = true;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.. It might help you with your problem..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/c8f624d0-8159-49b4-b38e-540fb7357ded